# How can I lock myself and all admins out of an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to create an S3 bucket and assign rights to 2 users in our company. But only those 2 users are allowed to have any sort of access to it.

There are several users including myself with administrative privileges. I need to revoke access to everyone, including myself. I need to ensure that no one can reverse this revocation, not even myself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the NotPrincipal Deny pattern.  Using a S3 Resource Policy

1. Deny everybody except the users who have access
2. Allow the 2 users who need access.  You can either add the access in the resource policy as I have below or attach it to their IAM identity policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOthers",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "USER_ARN"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOthers",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "USER_ARN"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, since you are the admin you just locked yourself out from admin the bucket unless you become the root user. So you might want to consider giving yourself bucket privileges without any object access.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOthers",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "USER_ARNs",
                    "ADMIN_ARNs"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUsersAdminAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "USER_ARN"
                ]
            },
             "NotAction": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
              ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUsersAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "USER_ARN"
                ]
            },
             "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:PutObject*",
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:RestoreObject*",
                "s3:ListBucket"
              ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAdminObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "ADMIN_ARN"
                ]
            },
             "Action": [
                "s3:*"
              ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAdminAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "ADMIN_ARN"
                ]
            },
             "NotAction": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
              ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET",
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I took a short cut on the admin access by only including the BUCKET in the resource and not any of the object (BUCKET/*).  Also, since most admin have a S3:* access in the IAM identity policy I added the explicit deny for admin to object access just to make sure.

WARNING: test in an account that you have root access to as the deny policies as the deny policies can easily lock everybody out of the bucket.

Comment: @WaitDe could an admin just delete this policy and allow themselves in later?

Comment: @kane you are correct with the second policy, but not the first policy. However, instead of locking out all admin access because you know the access list will change over time I recommend creating an AWS Config or CloudWatch CloudTrail event that sends out a notice on a policy change. You can also put a MFA requirement on policy change as well which would make a change a deliberate action.   Note that you have the same question if you use organizations as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to **create a separate AWS Account** so that nobody has access. This is quite common when handling sensitive information such as HR data. The accounts can be connected via **AWS Organizations**.

If you *did* want to do it within the same account, you'd need to create a **Bucket Policy that denies all permissions** except for the two given users. The only way these permissions could then be reversed is via those two users (if they are given permission to do so) or via the root login for the account.

Things get a little difficult and a little confusing when using such `Deny` policies since you can inadvertently lockout *all* people. Therefore, I'd recommend using the separate account.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about AWS Organizations. We may go that route after I talk to them some more about this